# Understanding performance issues for ionic 4 app using firebase realtime database

Tags: performance, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic4

I have a ionic 4 app using firebase real time database. On app start the data fetch happens from firebase db using angularfire2.

This is taking 13 seconds with just 40 objects. To understand the issue I installed the app and opened it in the chrome debugger to see the network activity.

What I am seeing is that the network activity shows "Stalled" status for those 13 sec and like 0.2 ms for data download. Attached is a screenshot. Please note that you will see in the screenshot every odd entry with that behavior. This is like 2 tabs in my app. tab1 has the issue and tab2 is just a regular tab. so i am tapping between the two see that it is consistent.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0d0jgi1o8dfpyq/Screenshot%202019-12-16%2021.49.55.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h43rschhi1domsh/Screenshot%202019-12-16%2021.56.52.png?dl=0

The code that is invoked is below:

```
async refreshData(){
    this.syncedCards = []
    const res:any = await this.dataSvc.getPendingCards(this.getUserKey())
    for(let cardQ of res){
      if(cardQ._status == GlobalVariables.QUEUED || cardQ._status ==  GlobalVariables.REJECTED)
         continue

      var card = this.copyContactDataFromJson(cardQ)
      this.syncedCards.push(card)

   }
  }

copyContactDataFromJson(cardQ:any){
    var card = new Card(cardQ._tempContactId, cardQ._frontImageUrl,cardQ._backImageUrl, cardQ._status, cardQ._date, cardQ._userId, cardQ._message, cardQ._objectType)
    card.firstName = cardQ._firstName
    card.lastName = cardQ._lastName
    card.jobTitle = cardQ._jobTitle
    card.company = cardQ._company
    card.email = cardQ._email
    card.mobile = cardQ._mobile
    card.workPhone = cardQ._workPhone
    card.website = cardQ._website
    card.street = cardQ._street
    card.city = cardQ._city
    card.state = cardQ._state
    card.country = cardQ._country
    card.postalCode = cardQ._postalCode 
    card.favoriteContact = cardQ._favoriteContact
    card.profilePic = cardQ._profilePic
    card.dept = cardQ._dept
    card.fax = cardQ._fax
    card.workPhoneExtn = cardQ._workPhoneExtn
}
```

The data service fetching this is below

```
getPendingCards(userKey:string){
    console.log("userkey to fetch data is:" + userKey)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.list("/users/" + userKey + "/cards", ref => ref.orderByChild('_date') )
      .valueChanges().subscribe(
        (res:any) => {
            resolve(res)
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err)
        }
      )}
    )
  }
```

Comment: Had you tried doing it without wrapping it into a promise? Also, can you use this technique to log the time of the request... 
``).pipe(
      timestamp(),
      map(stamp => [stamp.timestamp - start, stamp.value]),
      tap((result) => {
        console.log('Result with timestamp ', result);
      })
``

Comment: what is stamp.timestamp ? can you please write bit more elaborated? also how without using promise will help?